# Applying an Excel VBA single row macro to a cell range

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone explain how to get this Macro to run on entire columns instead for a single row of cells please? i.e. check values of each individual cell and perform the required calculation and output in the respective cell on its row.

```
Sub Calculate_Costs()
If Cells(2, 7) = "One Man" And Cells(2, 6) >= Cells(2, 5) Then
Cells(2, 8) = 6.5 + ((Cells(2, 6) - 20) * 0.23)
ElseIf Cells(2, 7) = "One Man" And Cells(2, 6) < Cells(2, 5) Then
Cells(2, 8) = 6.5 + ((Cells(2, 5) - 20) * 0.23)
ElseIf Cells(2, 7) = "Two Man" And Cells(2, 6) >= Cells(2, 5) Then
Cells(2, 8) = 38 + ((Cells(2, 6) - 50) * 0.38)
ElseIf Cells(2, 7) = "Two Man" And Cells(2, 6) < Cells(2, 5) Then
Cells(2, 8) = 38 + ((Cells(2, 5) - 50) * 0.38)
Else
Cells(2, 14) = "This is not working"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim row As Integer
row = 1
While Cells(row, 7) <> ""
    //Your original code here but with 2 replaced with row
    row = row + 1
Wend
```

Loops through all rows in column 7 until it hits a blank cell.